# Check date from all the tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've had like lists of 300 tables.

Every table has date column `INSERT_DATE` (of type `Varchar`).

And I wanted to check if the table is having the same date.

So that let's say - first table:

| INSERT_DATE |
| --- |
| 20221231 |
| 20221231 |
| 20221231 |

Second table:

| INSERT_DATE |
| --- |
| 20221231 |
| 20221231 |
| 20221231 |

Third table:

| INSERT_DATE |
| --- |
| 20221230 |
| 20221230 |
| 20221230 |

Desired results of my query:

| Table Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| FIRST_TABLE | 20221231 |
| SECOND_TABLE | 20221231 |
| THIRD_TABLE | 20221230 |

I'm confused on how to make it all "automatic" rather than querying one by one.

Like it'd take forever for me to query

```
SELECT TOP 1 INSERT_DATE 
FROM FIRST_TABLE
```

then

```
SELECT TOP 1 INSERT_DATE 
FROM SECOND_TABLE
```

then

```
SELECT TOP 1 INSERT_DATE 
FROM THIRD_TABLE
```

Until it'd get to 300 tables.
Btw , each of the tables would have only and should have only 1 date. Because the procedure was to truncate insert, so if i saw some tables not matching the dates like the others, i knew that table have some problems and i'd have to run it manually.

Comment: Sorry my bad..., it should've shown results of 20221230 instead

Comment: "Every table has date column INSERT_DATE (of type Varchar)."  - this is a mistake repeated 300 times. Use `DATE` datatype for dates

Comment: Are the 300 tables all storing essentially the same thing but just for a different date? If so that is also a mistake

Comment: You want to iterate all the tables without having to type them manually, correct?  Something like, for each name in sys.tables, select top 1 insert_date from table ?

Comment: How important is it for you to have the results output as a _query result_? If it's all the same to you, then I'd recommend to use AWK to generate a script containing 300 queries, have `sqlcmd` execute the script, and capture the result in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to scan the database's INFORMATION_SCHEMA to select all tables of interest and then build and execute dynamic SQL that queries each selected table and UNIONs the result.

It was unclear whether you wanted the top/max insert date or a distinct list of insert dates, so I have included SQL templates for both.

The following will select all tables having an INSERT_DATE column, and will build up and execute the necessary dynamic SQL.

```
-- Select tables
DECLARE @SelectedTables TABLE(TableName SYSNAME)
INSERT @SelectedTables
SELECT T.TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
    ON C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
    AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
WHERE T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
AND C.COLUMN_NAME = 'INSERT_DATE'

  -- Define SQL Templates
DECLARE @SqlTemplateMax NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT TABLE_NAME = <TableNameString>, MAX(INSERT_DATE) AS INSERT_DATE FROM <TableName>
'
DECLARE @SqlTemplateDistinct NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME = <TableNameString>, INSERT_DATE FROM <TableName>
'
DECLARE @UnionAll NVARCHAR(10) = 'UNION ALL
'
DECLARE @OrderBy NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'ORDER BY
    TABLE_NAME,
    INSERT_DATE DESC
'

-- Build dynamic SQL
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(
        REPLACE(REPLACE(@SqlTemplateDistinct
            ,'<TableNameString>', QUOTENAME(T.TableName, ''''))
            ,'<TableName>', QUOTENAME(T.TableName))
        , @UnionAll)
    FROM @SelectedTables T
)
SET @Sql = @Sql + @OrderBy

-- Print and Execute dynamic SQL
PRINT @Sql
EXEC (@Sql)
```

This will generate and execure the following dynamic SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME = 'FIRST_TABLE', INSERT_DATE FROM [FIRST_TABLE]
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME = 'SECOND_TABLE', INSERT_DATE FROM [SECOND_TABLE]
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME = 'THIRD_TABLE', INSERT_DATE FROM [THIRD_TABLE]
ORDER BY
    TABLE_NAME,
    INSERT_DATE DESC
```

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lYZWBNJk) for a working example.

Note the use of the `QUOTENAME()` function above. Its use is good practice to ensure proper escaping of potential special characters when injecting `'strings'` and `[identifiers]` into dynamic SQL.

The `STRING_AGG()` function joins the generated SQL fragments together, separated by the second parameter (`UNION ALL` in this case). If you are using an older version of SQL server that does not support `STRING_AGG()`, you will need to resort for using a `FOR XML` hack that was commonly used in the past to concatenate strings. See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gMHaVWE6) for the `FOR XML` version of the above.